# jQuery element exists event

Tags: jquery, events, exists

Is there an event or simple function for a calling a callback once a specific element exists on the page.
I am not asking how to check if an element exists.

as an example

```
$("#item").exists(function(){ });
```

I ended up using the ready event

```
 $("#item").ready(function(){ });
```

Comment: The ready function doesn't seem to work in this way @Drake. See this fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YDn5f/

Answer (score 3):

The [LiveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) jQuery plugin seems to be what most people are using to solve this problem.

> Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or
>   firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the
>   page has been loaded and the DOM updated.

Here's a quick jsfiddle that I put together to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/87WZ3/1/

Here's a demo of firing an event each time a div is created and writing out the unique id of the div that was just created: http://jsfiddle.net/87WZ3/2/

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem, so I went ahead and wrote a plugin for it: https://gist.github.com/4200601

`$(selector).waitUntilExists(function);`

Code:

```
(function ($) {

/**
* @function
* @property {object} jQuery plugin which runs handler function once specified element is inserted into the DOM
* @param {function} handler A function to execute at the time when the element is inserted
* @param {bool} shouldRunHandlerOnce Optional: if true, handler is unbound after its first invocation
* @example $(selector).waitUntilExists(function);
*/

$.fn.waitUntilExists    = function (handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, isChild) {
    var found       = 'found';
    var $this       = $(this.selector);
    var $elements   = $this.not(function () { return $(this).data(found); }).each(handler).data(found, true);

    if (!isChild)
    {
        (window.waitUntilExists_Intervals = window.waitUntilExists_Intervals || {})[this.selector] =
            window.setInterval(function () { $this.waitUntilExists(handler, shouldRunHandlerOnce, true); }, 500)
        ;
    }
    else if (shouldRunHandlerOnce && $elements.length)
    {
        window.clearInterval(window.waitUntilExists_Intervals[this.selector]);
    }

    return $this;
}

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the .live function. It executes on all current and future elements in the selector.

$('div').live( function() {});